# Get out of FOR loop

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically adding text fields (maximum 32) into my page and I need to go through all of them and check, if all of them are empty I will display a warning message! I don't want to use **document.getElementsByTagName('input')** cause I have others text files on the page apart of dynamic ones!

I don't know why when I'm using this code below it doesn't allow me to get out from FOR loop and print **alert('Test')** and print warning?

Could anyone help me to sort this problem! Thanks!

```
        var counter=0

        for(var i = 1; i <= 32; i++){                   
            var e = document.getElementById('mytextfieldid'+i).value;

            if(e==''){}
            else{counter++;}
        }

        alert('Test');
        if(counter==0){DisplayWarning();}
```

Comment: Try adding `break;` to leave the loop if you really want to do that

Comment: You should add a common class to these elements and use `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing

```
document.getElementById('mytextfieldid'+i).value
```

you assume `document.getElementById('mytextfieldid'+i)` exists. If not it will raise an error and stop code execution.

You need to test the element before accessing the value.

```
var element = document.getElementById('mytextfieldid'+i);
if(element){
   // update your counter...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sure it does, please argue. The OP wonders why the alert is not executing, this answer gives an explanation.

Comment: @mguimard Still the same doesn't allow me to print a warning message :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that ALL elements are blank you might want to try using a flag. If any values are hit change the flag and break out of the loop.

NOTE: Breaks tend to make things a little harder to follow.

```
    var empty = true;

    for(var i = 1; i <= 32; i++){                   
        var e = document.getElementById('mytextfieldid'+i);

        if(e && e.value !=''){
            console.log(e);
            empty = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    alert('Test');
    if(empty){DisplayWarning();}
```

Comment: Still the same doesn't allow me to print a warning message :(

Comment: Can you throw a `console.log(e);` inside of the if in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of elements is variable, why is the loop always going to 32?  I would have it be a variable that matches the number of the last dynamically added field.